# Why does Hadamard claim that Pascal could have discovered non-Euclidean geometry

Tags: logic, math-history, philosophy

In *The psychology of invention in the mathematical field*, p. 53, Hadamard makes the following claim:

[image]

Is his point that there must, in any axiomatic theory, be undefined terms, and if you write the parallel postulate entirely expanded, i.e., with definiens substituted for definiendum , then you will see that its not a truth of logic? But that seems completely off. You may still "see" that its a truth for perceptual space (let us grant, for the sake of the argument), and moreover, you may still *fail to see* that it isn't implied by the other axioms+logic. Thus, while you *may* arguably conceive of the possiblity of non-Euclidean axiom systems, you might still not yet perceive that of non-Euclidean *geometries* (qua sciences of space); and in fact, without a proof of relative consistency of these systems, e.g. by an inner model in Euclidean geometry, or by a model in **R**, you aren't technically allowed to even assume so much as the possibility of these systems, since (lacking such proof), the PP might -- for all you know -- after all be a consequence of the other axioms.

Am I completely misunderstanding Hadamard's point here?

Comment: I do not think he claims that Pascal could have discovered non-Euclidean geometry.

Comment: But what do you think his claim is, then?

Comment: This question should be asked on [History of Science and Mathematics](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: My guess is that he meant that Pascal could have discovered Hilbert's notion of formal axiomatic systems, whose truth is independent of their correspondence with our physical world. But this is a guess only.

Comment: This is also my guess (I literally this second added it as an edit to this version https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/13044/why-does-hadamard-claim-that-pascal-could-have-discovered-non-euclidean-geometry), but then what's the business with "the true meaning" of Euclid's postulate?

Comment: A formal statement involving primitive notions would be it true meaning.

Comment: Hm. That's an interesting point. So it would be regarded as expressing a structural feature of all its possible interpretations, rather than (exclusively) one of perceptual or physical space? Or what is the meaning of the primitives? If they are still interpreted uniquely as refering to perceptual/physical space, then that meaning is precisely the same that Euclid had in mind. So Pascal ought to have anticipated a modern type of semantic theory, is that it?

Comment: @10012511: I would not go as far as saying "ought" but "could." However, this is just my reading of a single Hadamard's sentence and it would not surprise me if there were other options.

Comment: I think yours is an interesting interpretation, but I agree that this passage offers more than one. It is the only thing he says about this subject in this book, btw, before and after the paragraph I quoted he discusses other points.

Answer (score 3):

> Why, according to Hadamard, Pascal *could* have discovered non-Euclidean geometry?

Let start from Euclid's definition:

> *Definition 23* Parallel straight lines are straight lines which, being in the same plane and being produced indefinitely in both directions, do not meet one another in either direction.

The issue is not about substitution of *definiens* in place of *definiendum* in the statement of the postulate.

The original text of [Euclid's Postulate 5](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/%7Edjoyce/elements/bookI/bookI.html#defs) does not use the definiendum "parallel lines" but refers to the "meeting condition" of the definies:

> *Postulate 5*. That, if a straight line falling on two straight lines makes the interior angles on the same side less than two right angles, the two straight lines, if produced indefinitely, meet on that side on which are the angles less than the two right angles.

The issue is to note that in Post.5 Euclid uses a property of lines: *to meet* that is not mentioned in any other postulates.

Thus, we cannot derive anything about "lines meeting" from them.

Obviously, it is not easy at all to note this fact: the modern concept of *model* (the intuitive one) dates from late XIX Century and was very far away from Ancient and Early Modern mathematics.

Hilbert's proof is a *mathematical* proof, and not an intuition (made with hindsight).

The question posed by Hadamard can be rewritten as: can Pascal have had that intuition without a development of mathematics comparable to that of Hilbert?

Comment: That is a really great point, thank you! But is it really that easy to see that the PP is not derivable from the other axioms (or axioms equivalent to them) in this way? Why then did Hilbert go to such lengths in Grundlagen to prove its independence? Certainly, there are axioms missing in Euclid's presentation (or rather, implicitly presupposed), e.g., ensuring that a line cutting a circle must intersect it, which, when supplemented, would undermine your interpretation? What Pascal could have seen from his principles is that the axioms are incomplete, not that PP is independent, right?

Comment: Also, thanks for correcting my sloppy latin :)